# Trigger Transact-SQL en Azure SQL Database y Azure Web Apps

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, webforms, azure, azure-sql

Estoy planteándome subir varias webs **Asp.net (webforms)** a **Azure Web Apps**. Todas ellas tienen bases de datos en el **SQL Server** que actualmente están en el mismo server que el sitio web. (Un servidor propietario)

No he utilizado **Azure** todavía, por lo que entiendo que necesito los servicios:

> - Azure SQL Database
> - Azure Web Apps

Las bases de datos de las webs disponen de `DML Triggers` en `Transact-SQL`, del tipo `DELETE, UPDATE... AFTER INSERT`, por ejemplo.

He oído que **Azure SQL Database** soporta procedimientos almacenados pero **NO** soporta triggers de este tipo. Incluso me lo comentaron en una presentación reciente de Azure, un técnico de Microsoft

**¿Esto es así?**

En los siguientes enlaces, se habla de ello como que **SÍ LO SOPORTA** y dice que se aplica a **AZURE SQL Database**:

[Enlace 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-dml-triggers?view=sql-server-2017) , [Enlace 2](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/azure-sql/list-triggers)

Si es así, tendría que modificar todo el planteamiento de las webs, ya que las bases de datos se modifican, etc... mediante `Triggers`.

Sería importante saber si alguien de vosotros tiene algo corriendo ya en **Azure SQL Database** con `Triggers`.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación dice puedes crear Triggers en Azure SQL 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

No creo que necesites adecuar la arquitectura de tu app en ese sentido al menos.

Por otro lado, al utilizar Azure SQL Server, debes cambiar tu estrategia de monitoreo y análisis de performance, la forma de encontrar Locks, queries que se bloquean etc... Piensa en utilizar Azure application insights para llevar a cabo parte del análisis que haría un DBA teniendo el SQL Server en un server inhouse
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-intelligent-insights

Answer (score 1):

Me respondo a mi mismo, por si sirve de ayuda para otros usuarios.

He trasladado 3 webs **Asp.net (webforms)** a **Azure Web Apps** todas ellas tenían una base de datos en su servidor SQL (Estaban alojadas en un **Windows 2003 Server**, con un **SQL Server 2000**) y las he publicado desde **Visual Studio 2015** y un **SQL Sever 2012**

En Azure he creado el servicio **Azure Web Apps** y **Azure SQL Database**

> **1ª Web**  Un sitio sencillo en **Visual Basic ASP.NET 4.0** y **BootStrap** para los estilos.
>   Incluye algunas rutinas sencillas en **javascript** y **jquery**. Sin Base de datos.
>
> - **https://reversa.es**

Al desplegarla en Azure desde VisualStudio, la traspasó al completo sin tener que hacer nada. 
Solamente he encontrado una pega, **una de las páginas tiene un vídeo incrustado y no sabe mostrarlo**

*"Tengo que averiguar el problema, todavía"*

> **2ª Web**  Un sitio escrito en **C# webforms ASP.NET 4.0** y **BootStrap** para los estilos.
>   Incluye algunas rutinas sencillas en **javascript** y **jquery**. 
>   Tiene una base de datos en **SQL Server 2000** para mostrar todos los productos, generación de menús, etc...compatible con **ODBC**.
>
> También tiene un apartado interno para poder introducir nuevos productos, subir fotos, etc... directamente en la db. Hay otros tantos procedimientos almacenados.
>
> - **https://ouver.com**

Para desplegarla en Azure desde VisualStudio, se tubo que retocar la cadena de conexión del web.config activando la transformación en el fichero deploy, de esta forma corre perfectamente en local y hace el cambio cuando publica.

En esta web no supo subir las bases de datos desde VisualStudio, *"supongo que por viejas"*   Solamente tuve que instalar **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18** y exportar la bases de datos desde ahí al **Azure SQL Database**. Se creó todo perfectamente, incluidos los procedimientos almacenados. **Funciona correctamente.**

> **3ª Web**  Un sitio algo complejillo, escrito en **C# webforms ASP.NET 4.0** y **BootStrap** para los estilos.  Incluye algunas rutinas sencillas en **javascript** y **jquery**. 
>   Tiene varias bases de datos en **SQL Server 2012** con **ADO.NET** utilizando **SQLDatasource** y por supuesto con bastantes procedimiento almacenados y varios **TRIGGERS qué SÍ FUNCIONAN**
>   También tiene el sistema de securización sobre la db de SQL.
>
> Esta web gestiona internamente sistemas IoT, contenido publicitario de clientes y audio streaming, pero solo para dispositivos que se conectan y son reconocidos. 
>   *Por lo tanto hay poco para el usuario de a pie.*
>
> - **https://AiConnex.com**

Prácticamente VisualStudio desplegó por completo en Azure todo. Incluidas las bases de datos con sus Triggers. Hubo que descargar una librería NUGET requerida para que gestionara correctamente los esquemas de las dbs y listo.

El único problema encontrado es que no supo crear correctamente la tabla de Roles de usuarios, los cuales no funcionaban correctamente. Solo tuve que entrar con el usuario correcto y volver a crear los roles, asignar los usuarios y listo. *Menos mal que no había miles de usuarios*

Aun estoy con esta última web, ya que me falta probar unas pantallas LED que recogen el contenido publicado por una aplicación, el resto, incluido la mayoría de dispositivos IoT y el tema de música en los reproductores, funciona correctamente.

Espero os ayude

Comment: Excelente! Creo que el tema del video es que no se haya publicado o esta mal el link (si el video esta incluido en VS verificaste que este seleccionado sobre el archivo que se incluya en el deploy? eso se hace a mano ya que no lo toma de forma automatica)

Comment: Con respecto a los datos de la tabla de Roles, tal vez es por algún setting incompatible entre versiones, pero bien que fue solo eso y fácil resolver

Comment: Acuérdate que desde local tb puedes apuntar a la BD que esta en Azure y probar directamente (por si tienes que hacer pruebas en algún momento con datos que estén allí)